# Correcting one code causes another to stop working

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am working on a document in which clickable cells place different values in column M on sheets 1 and 3. On sheet 1 when column M reads COMPLETE it will be cut from sheet 1 and pasted in sheet 2 when column M reads PARTIAL HOLD it will be cut from sheet 1 and pasted into sheet 3. I am having many problems with this but the problem I am asking for help on here is that in the following code the moves will work but i get a "run-time error '424' Object Required" and is not accepting Time as an object in my line of code Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time but when I fix the issue in the code for the clickable cells the rows will no longer cut and paste.

This first code is the code that allows the rows to move but gets me an error

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDest As Range, rngDest2 As Range, rngDest3 As Range
          If UCase(Target.Value) = "PARTIAL HOLD" Then
            Set rngDest = Sheet3.Range("A5:Q5")
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("M5:M290")) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.EntireRow.Cut
                rngDest.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Target.EntireRow.Delete
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        ElseIf UCase(Target.Value) = "PROGRESSING" Then
            Set rngDest3 = Sheet1.Range("A5:Q5")
            If Not Intersect(Sheet3.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), Sheet3.Range("M5:M290")) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.EntireRow.Cut
                rngDest3.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Target.EntireRow.Delete
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        ElseIf UCase(Target.Value) = "COMPLETE" Then
            Set rngDest2 = Sheet2.Range("A5:Q5")
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("M5:M290")) Is Nothing Then
                 Application.EnableEvents = False
                 Target.EntireRow.Cut
                 rngDest2.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                 Target.EntireRow.Delete
                 Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
       If Target.Column = 11 Then
          Cancel = True
          Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "IN PROGRESS"
          Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time
       ElseIf Target.Column = 12 Then
          Cancel = True
          Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "COMPLETE"
          Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time
       ElseIf Target.Column = 14 Then
          Cancel = True
          Target.Offset(, -1).Value = "PARTIAL HOLD"
       End If
    End Sub
```

The next code is the correction I have made to the clickable cells, but this stops the rows from cutting and pasting

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDest As Range, rngDest2 As Range, rngDest3 As Range
         If UCase(Target.Value) = "PARTIAL HOLD" Then
            Set rngDest = Sheet3.Range("A5:Q5")
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("M5:M290")) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.EntireRow.Cut
                rngDest.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Target.EntireRow.Delete
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        ElseIf UCase(Target.Value) = "PROGRESSING" Then
            Set rngDest3 = Sheet1.Range("A5:Q5")
            If Not Intersect(Sheet3.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), 
      Sheet3.Range("M5:M290")) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.EntireRow.Cut
                rngDest3.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Target.EntireRow.Delete
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        ElseIf UCase(Target.Value) = "COMPLETE" Then
            Set rngDest2 = Sheet2.Range("A5:Q5")
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("M5:M290")) Is Nothing Then
                 Application.EnableEvents = False
                 Target.EntireRow.Cut
                 rngDest2.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                 Target.EntireRow.Delete
                 Application.EnableEvents = True
           End If
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Xit:
       If Target.Column = 11 Then
          Cancel = True
          Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "IN PROGRESS"
          Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time
       ElseIf Target.Column = 12 Then
          Cancel = True
          Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "COMPLETE"
          Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time
       ElseIf Target.Column = 14 Then
          Cancel = True
          Target.Offset(, -1).Value = "PARTIAL HOLD"
       End If
    Xit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: _This first code is the code that allows the rows to move but gets me an error_ What's the error and which line does it occur on?  I take it the sheets codenames are `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`?  It might be better to rename these to something more obvious -  `shtComplete`, `shtPartial`, `shtProgressing` perhaps.

Comment: I am using sheet 1 sheet 2 and sheet 3 because that is the test booklet, in my actual document the sheets have real names Active Work Orders, Complete Work Orders, Partial Work Orders (respectively) . I am getting run-time error '424' Object required. When I click debug it highlights line 9 in code Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick or line 40 counting from the first line of code i posted. As I mentioned, the second box code that i posted fixes the problem but then the rows don't move

Comment: Line 9 being `Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time`?

Comment: Yes that line. Essentially the code doesn't like having Time as an object